# python elementtree - getting average

Tags: python

Using element tree in python, I want to get an average value.

Below is my data

```
Order A has a quantity of 12,10,and 5.. total is 27
Order B has a quantity of 9 and 40... total is 49
Order C has a quantity of 10,35, and 15.. total is 60
```

When you total them then divide by 3, I should be getting 45.33.  But on my code below, I'm getting 20. :(  I'm extracting the above data from an XML file.  Can you please help me identify the problem on my code.  Thank you.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
root = ET.ElementTree(file="nwind_medium.xml")

orders = root.findall("./orders")
for order in orders:
    orderdetails = order.findall("./orderdetails")
    total = 0
    for detail in orderdetails:
        quantity = detail.findall("./quantity")
        total += float(quantity[0].text)
numberOrders = len(orders)

print "The average number of itmes in order is", round((total / numberOrders),2)
```

Here's the whole XML file (updated)

- - - Vins et alcools Chevalier VINET  - - 72 Mozzarella di Giovanni  34.8 5 - 14 Formaggi Fortini s.r.l.   - - 11 Queso Cabrales  14 12 - 5 Cooperativa de Quesos 'Las Cabras'   - - 42 Singaporean Hokkien Fried Mee  9.8 10 - 20 Leka Trading    - - Toms Spezialitaten TOMSP  - - 14 Tofus  18.6 9 - 6 Mayumi's   - - 51 Manjimup Dried Apples  42.4 40 - 24 G'day, Mate    - - Hanari Carnes HANAR  - - 65 Louisiana Fiery Hot Pepper Sauce  16.8 15 - 2 New Orleans Cajun Delights   - - 41 Jack's New England Clam Chowder  7.7 10 - 19 New England Seafood Cannery   - - 51 Manjimup Dried Apples  42.4 35 - 24 G'day, Mate

Comment: @suer_new_in_python Could you provide your xml in more readable format?

Comment: Can I paste that on the original question?

Comment: what is `quantity[0].text` each time through the loop?

Comment: @user_new_in_python Your XML is broken, apart of funny `-` and `+` the

Comment: @user_new_in_python Not yet there. I mean an XML, which can be copied into text editor, saved, and validated as valid XML. No "-" or "+", but all the elements closed. You can remove all the elements, which are not necessary for showing the problem, but you shall provide valid XML.

Comment: Sorry, I think I'm having some issues on my browser when pasting the XML file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are resetting total on each iteration through an order. If you need total of all orders move

```
total = 0
```

before the outer loop.

Comment: Yay...that was "easy".  Thank you

Comment: @user_new_in_python, If some answer solves your problem please don't forget to vote for it. And welcome to SO!

Comment: Hi, are you referring to the check mark?  I already did that.